# Checkbox values on submit

Tags: php, checkbox, submit

What I want to do is to display values from database on checkbox labels. I already did that part:

```
$acc = $truckerController->GetAccessory();
$acc_result = "<form action='' method='post'>";
foreach ($acc as $value) {
$id = $value->id;
$device = $value->device;
$acc_result .= "<input type='checkbox' name='$device' id='$device' value='$id'>"
        . "<label for='$device'>$device</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}
$acc_result .= "<input type='submit' name='acc_submit' value='submit'><form/>";
echo $acc_result;
```

but what I want to accomplish is when submitting checked values I can't seem to get the checked values.

```
if (isset($_POST["acc_submit"])) {
        echo $_POST["$device"];
}
```

Help please!

Comment: The value of a checkbox is only submitted if the checkbox is checked. Therefore you need to check whether `$_POST[$device]` is set (=checked) or not (=unchecked)

Comment: okay i get that part. but another problem is if i check and submit the second checkbox it won't display it. only the first one on the array is displaying. any idea simon?

Comment: I don't see a second checkbox in your code?